# Detect an element has a particular class when Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to do effect like this: http://showstudio.com/

When slide to other slides, change the color (add class) for title or somewhere.

First, I need to detect div which has "white" and add class to another div.

http://jsbin.com/ajeBeba/1/edit

Please help me to know which is "blue" & "orange" and I can follow up after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Fiddle. Its working.

http://jsfiddle.net/aBB48/

Check this one:-

```
if ( $( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "blue" ) )
  {
   alert('blue');
  }
else
  {
   alert('orange');
  }
```

Comment: Morning Anup , http://jsbin.com/ajeBeba/7/edit   could you take a look , i can't change it

Comment: one more question is :　i also tried   ----  $(".carousel-inner").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {   , and it worked as well . What's different between these two  "lid.bs.carousel" and "webkitTransitionEnd"  , thanks for your patient .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pete and Anup ,  I tried it .

Here is my updated .

http://jsbin.com/ajeBeba/7/edit

how could I change color of these two slides .

Facebook > Different Color:blue

Google+ >  Different Color:orange

Your strong support is very much appreciated.

Thanks so much .

Comment: Change the line the 'else' statement to:
$(".textArea").removeClass("orange").addClass("blue");

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".active div").attr("class") == "fill blue")
{
  alert("blue");
}
```

Tested on your JS Bin and it works.

Update:

```
if($(".active div").hasClass("blue"))
{
  alert("blue");
}
```

Also works...

Comment: There is a problem in your bind event.